# SQL copy field from one table into another in wordpress

Tags: sql, copy

I am trying to copy the `post_title` field from table `wp_posts` into the `meta_value` field in table `wp_postmeta`. These are wordpress tabkes.

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET wp_postmeta.meta_value = wp_posts.post_title 
FROM wp_posts,wp_postmeta 
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE '%_yoast_wpseo_focuskw'
```

Getting this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM wp_posts,wp_postmeta WHERE wp_posts.ID =
>   wp_postmeta.post_id AND wp_pos' at line 3

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta m INNER JOIN
       wp_posts p ON p.ID = m.post_id 
   SET m.meta_value = p.post_title 
WHERE  m.meta_key LIKE '%_yoast_wpseo_focuskw'
```

Comment: Many thanks this worked great. Thanks, can you add a comment where I went wrong, it seems that my statement made sense but obviously it was wrong.

Comment: You're very welcome. In Mysql in multi-table `UPDATE` table references (no `FROM`) go first, then `SET` clause and then `WHERE` (optional). See [UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have an UPDATE with the table names, and then have a FROM clause doing the same thing.  Either combine the tables you need in the UPDATE clause, or you need a SELECT for a sub query.

In any case, the FROM is not correct syntax.  You can Google for SQL syntax or for the SQL syntax specific to MySQL, which might help you with what is legal SQL for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET wp_postmeta.meta_value = wp_posts.post_title 
FROM wp_posts
Inner join wp_postmeta on
 wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE '%_yoast_wpseo_focuskw'